# Bootstrap container not breaking text line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with getting my `container` text responsive on small devices. I have tried to do something, but nothing really got me to the point.
Take a look - I added my fiddle here! Try to make the result small and see what what happens in the blue container added below inverse menu with text "Mona Larsen" in it. Text is like just going forward not taking the words in next lines as it should be. What's the problem? 
[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/djemm1996/tL33zjvb/1/)

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? Its pretty unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your class

```
.description {
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
float: none;
margin-top: -125px;
margin-left: 200px;
color: #FFFFFF;}
```

change "position: absolute" into "Positon: relative"

```
.description {
text-align: left;
position: relative;
float: none;
margin-top: -125px;
margin-left: 200px;
color: #FFFFFF;}
```